# ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint in mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate-annotations

Hi iam creating two table in mysql for onetoone mapping in spring hibernate,but i am getting the error `ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint`

This is my first table

```
CREATE TABLE `Employee` (  `empId` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`empName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  `empExp` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`empTeam` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  `teamId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL);
```

second table

```
CREATE TABLE `EmpTeam` (  `teamId` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`teamName` varchar(255) DEFAULT     NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`teamId`)  ,
 KEY `FK1` (`teamId`), CONSTRAINT `FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`teamId`) 
 REFERENCES `Employee`   (`empId`));
```

Please help,thanks in advance

Comment: To get a detailed error: run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and look at the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" section

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  CREATE TABLE `EmpTeam` (  `teamId` int(11) NOT NULL, 
                            `teamName` varchar(255) DEFAULT     NULL,
                             PRIMARY KEY (`teamId`)  ,
                             CONSTRAINT `FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`teamId`) 
                             REFERENCES `Employee`   (`empId`));
```

if you already have this FK1 then remove it and create it again:

```
   alter table `EmpTeam` drop foreign key `FK1`
```

**EDIT:**

you have to add PRIMARY KEY also in your Employee table . and it should work.

change this

```
   CREATE TABLE `Employee` (  `empId` int(11) NOT NULL ,
```

to

```
   CREATE TABLE `Employee` (  `empId` int(11) NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY ,
```